# how to fix "insufficient funds for gas * price + value"?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, erc20

windows 10 Home  x64
bignumber.js@^7.2.1
openzeppelin-solidity@1.10.0
react@16.4.1
react-dom@16.4.1
truffle@4.1.13
web3@1.0.0-beta.34
Full version reference:
https://github.com/tooploox/ethereum-ico-examples/blob/master/package.json

I have done a lot of research. I found so many sources but none of them found a solution and some threads are not updated anymore or probably they already found an answer but did not post it. Some people manage to fix it in Mac, but I am using Windows. Some people fix it 5 months ago but when I tried it, it did not work out, buy changing the gas higher a little bit and run again. I also have `6 Ether` in my Ropsten account.

This is my `truffle.js`:

```
ropsten: {
  provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/"+infura_apikey),
  network_id: 3,
  gas: 4000000
},
```

when I `truffle migrate --network ropsten`:

```
it triggers this error:   
Running migration: 1_initial-migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

Github reference:
https://github.com/tooploox/ethereum-ico-examples
Instruction Reference:
https://www.tooploox.com/blog/create-and-distribute-your-erc20-token-with-openzeppelin

Comment: Have you tried reducing the gas price?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting gas price in truffle.js file.

```
    gasPrice: 10000000000 // Something price like this
```

[Source](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you! it really works and leads to another problem

Comment: This is the follow up question, you might wanna check thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53320530/how-to-fix-web3providerengine-does-not-support-synchronous-requests